# Redefine CSS order

Tags: html, css, import

My situation is this:

**file1.css**

```
.position-relative{ position : relative !important; }
```

**file2.css**

```
.my-class{ 
     ...
     position : absolute !important; 
 }
```

**my_page.html**

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file2.css">
...
<div class="my-class position-relative">
   ...
</div>
```

Now, if I open Chrome console, i can see that that div has as active `position:absolute` inherited by `my-class`, bu I want the `position: relative` of the second class to be the active one.
How can i achive it WITHOUT changing the order od the file import?

So far, i have tried to interchange the class order in the `div`, but nothing, and also redefine the `position-absolute` class in the header inside `<style> ... </style>`, and also this doesn't work.

Comment: Make CSS selector more speciffic.

Comment: @M1K1O yes, o course, i can also add a new class with only that property in the header, but because there is already one that does it, i was wishing to have a more elegant solution

Comment: If your selectors have same Specificity (even both are important) then decides whether they come form external source or `<style>` tag. If they both come from external source, I am affraid, only order decides. @Berto99

Comment: This is a case of badly used `!important`… Nevertheless, you can double the class name or use the `[class]` hack (i.e. `.my-class.my-class` or `.my-class[class]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Remove the `!important` from file2.css

**Explanation**

You have given your `<div>` 2 class names:  "my-class" and "position-relative". In both your css files, you have specified the 2 classes "position" attribute.

Problem is, the position attribute cannot be relative and absolute at the same time.  But since your files define the position of ".my-class" and ".relative-position", AND your  class name is "my-class relative-position", this means it will pick the one you define last (Which is "absolute").

When you use `!important`, it ignores standard CSS3 order, including style written in your `<header>`.  However since you have `!important` on both file1.css and file2.css, and BOTH these files are manipulating the `position` attribute of your `<div>` (which has 2 class names), Therefore it prioritizes the `position : absolute` in file2.css.

Its important to understand that css is applied to HTML elements, not "classes".  The class name identifies which `<div>` to apply the style to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i can't, one is the template and the other one is bootstrap, and so idk where this !important is usefull inside the first class

Answer (score 0):

You can override style by being more specific with your element selection.

An example would be to simply add div to your class.

```
div.my-class {
   position: relative !important
}
```

You can go even further by doing:

```
div.my-class.position-relative {
   position: relative !important
}
```

Comment: Not much need for the div tag here, but otherwise correct.